# GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable as a git configuration

Tags: git, ssh

i am using [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode) and i tried to find whether there is a corresponding [git configuration](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sshvariant) so i could use rather than using the environment variable, though i couldn't find it.

is there a way to use git configuration for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` rather than specifying it as an environment variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22GIT_SSH_COMMAND%22+config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting is [`core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand), cf. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 0):

[core.sshCommand](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand)

> If this variable is set, git fetch and git push will use the specified
>   command instead of ssh when they need to connect to a remote system.
>   The command is in the same form as the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment
>   variable and is overridden when the environment variable is set.